# Can I use `enum class` as argument type of function at DLL boundary?

Tags: c++, enums

I got a enum class named `Animal` as the key for lookup. It is defined in `AnimalList.h`

```
enum class Animal{Dog, Cat}; // v1
```

And I got a DLL `AnimalInformation.dll` with a interface as following:

```
HRESULT GetDescription(Animal animal_key, char* buffer, int& size_in_buffer);
```

I know enum class is a strong-type version of enum. If some day I want to add available animals, is it safe to extend my Animal enum class?

```
AnimalList.h // v2

enum class Animal{Dog, Cat, Tiger, Lion};
```

Does the `Animal{Dog, Cat, Tiger, Lion}` match the `Animal{Dog, Cat}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typechecking happens during compilation, and the name-mangling that ensures different functions with different types have different names are based on the base-type and name of the class, so should give the same name for both your examples.

However, what you have to contend with is that `GetDescription(Animal animal_key, char* buffer, int& size_in_buffer)` won't know about `Tiger` and `Lion`, and return `ERR_ANIMAL_UNKNOWN` to the user-code that is trying to use it, if you have mismatched DLL's. Which wouldn't be very nice. This is of course a problem with ANY enum and any DLL that takes user-data and certain values are recognised and others are not.

Comment: Thanks. So it is OK to put enum class at DLL boundary except the problem that client might get `ERR_ANIMAL_UNKNOWN` message if he use the wrong version dll?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see. And it's only a problem if the client (user of the DLL) knows "more" values (of course, if you remove values, weird things will happen, unless you also fix the numeric values with `enum class Animal { Dog=0, Cat=1, Tiger=2 }`, then in the future we can remove `Cat` and still have the same values).